# How to convert a sbyte[] to byte[] in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I've got a function which fills an array of type sbyte[], and I need to pass this array to another function which accepts a parameter of type byte[].

Can I convert it nicely and quickly, without copying all the data or using `unsafe` magic?

Comment: just added some whitespace to the Q, hope you don't mind :D

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Yes, you can.
Since both `byte` and `sbyte` have the same binary representation there's no need to copy the data.
Just do a cast to Array, then cast it to `byte[]` and it'll be enough.

```
sbyte[] signed = { -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 };
byte[] unsigned = (byte[]) (Array)signed;
```

Comment: Wow, awesome! I hadn't thought of this. :P

Comment: Quite often i receive a mismatch array type using this approach

Comment: I tried this but it dint work. The results were question mark. Something that I have not seen before. Here is the code 
`sbyte[] txdata = { (0x00 | 0x20), ~(1 << 6) };
byte[] dss = (byte[])((Array)txdata);`

Comment: I have no idea why is not working for you. I just tried your code and works fine.

Comment: The debugger (visualizer) seems to have problems with the 'converted' array, but it still works fine :) +1

Comment: What this does is change the *compile-time type* of the array. Useful technique, but it depends what ends up consuming the result. For instance, System.Array.Copy(Array, int, Array, int, int) looks at the *runtime-type* of the two arrays and will throw an exception if you try to copy a "real" `byte[]` to a `sbyte[]` masquerading as a `byte[]`.

Comment: `unsigned.GetValue(0)` will also return its real value `-2`.

Comment: I get an error of "Cannot convert type 'sbyte[]' to 'byte[]'"

Comment: Does this alloc a new array of copy?

Answer (score 31):

You will have to copy the data (only reference-type arrays are covariant) - but we can try to do it efficiently; `Buffer.BlockCopy` seems to work:

```
    sbyte[] signed = { -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 };
    byte[] unsigned = new byte[signed.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(signed, 0, unsigned, 0, signed.Length);
```

If it was a reference-type, you can just cast the reference without duplicating the array:

```
    Foo[] arr = { new Foo(), new Foo() };
    IFoo[] iarr = (IFoo[])arr;
    Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(arr, iarr)); // true
```

Comment: @BoiseBaked I'm providing an answer by saying they need to copy the data and showing an efficient way to do that, aka "being helpful". The context of array covariance is relevant: in other virtually identical scenarios no copy is necessary. If your objection is the use of specific terms: get over it. This is a technical field with complex concepts. Using the correct terminology saves a lot of confusion. It isn't " self-gratifying", so please climb down off that high horse.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using .NET 3.5+, you can use the following:

```
byte[] dest = Array.ConvertAll(sbyteArray, (a) => (byte)a);
```

Which is, I guess effectively copying all the data.

Note this function is also in .NET 2.0, but you'd have to use an anonymous method instead.

Comment: Ugh. I'd rather use Buffer.BlockCopy() then. That at least blindly copies a bunch of bytes. This one has a function call for each of them. Performance nightmare.

Comment: Well, it all depends on how much you're copying, but yeah, The block copy makes more sense.

In the end, if you want type safety, the only way is to copy. If you want to convert (re-cast) the array, the unsafe is the only way to go.

Comment: LOL! Or you can do the same thing without the overhead: byte[] foo = (byte[])(Array)signed;

Comment: @BoiseBaked No, you can't. This won't change the runtime (element) type of the array.