# Is unsafe normal in .net C#?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string

I need do create a new instance of String from the array of sbytes (sbyte[]).
For that I need to convert sbyte[] into sbyte*

It is possible only using unsafe keyword.
is that okay or is there any other ways to create a String from array of sbytes?

Comment: `sbyte` is pretty rare in .NET; is this some ported java code perhaps? `byte` (unsigned) is far more common.

Comment: What an interesting question - +1 for that!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First: 
[How to convert a sbyte[] to byte[] in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829983/how-to-convert-a-sbyte-to-byte-in-c)

```
sbyte[] signed = { -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 };
byte[] unsigned = (byte[]) (Array)signed;
```

Then:

```
string yourstring = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(unsigned);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using sbyte?

Encoding.Default.GetString() (and any other encoding) takes a `byte[]` Array as argument, so you could convert the  `sbyte[]` Array using LINQ if all values are non-negative: `array.Cast<byte>().ToArray()`.

Comment: Maybe he's using C somewhere else