# Error with converting an image to byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, system.drawing

I have a script trying to convert an image into a byte array, but cannot get it to output the array.

Using

`Console.WriteLine(bytearray);`

I just get an output of

`System.Byte[]`

and when trying

`return bytearray;`
I get the error

```
    'Program.Main(string[])' returns void, a return keyword must not be 
    followed by an object expression
```

```
byte[] bytearray;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    bytearray = ms.ToArray();
    Console.WriteLine (bytearray);
}
```

I would like to have the byte array for the image output to the console. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#: Converting byte array to string and printing out to console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940883/c-converting-byte-array-to-string-and-printing-out-to-console)

Comment: Note that the accepted answer in the linked possible duplicate is about converting a byte array containing character code points of some encoding into text, and thus is unsuitable for the problem at hand.

Comment: There are *two* problems in this code. The one that generates the error is that you tried to use `return bytearray` in a `void` method. The second is that you tried to print a byte array without specifying *how* to do that

Answer (score 2):

`Console.WriteLine` outputs a `string` to the console. But the argument can be any object, not just a string. So if the argument is some other type (like a byte array) then it calls the object's `ToString()` method and writes that out. This always works because everything inherits from `object` and therefore every object has a `ToString()` method.

But more often than not, that `ToString()` method isn't overridden. So it just executes `object.ToString()` which returns the name of the type of the object.

That's why if you do this:

```
var byteArray = new byte[] { };
Console.WriteLine(byteArray);
```

You get this:

> System.Byte[]

You probably want to see the individual values, but `ToString()` doesn't return that. It just returns the name of the type. So if you wanted to actually output the values for each byte you would have to do that explicitly:

```
foreach(var b in byteArray) 
    Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Now you're not calling `WriteLine(object)`. You're calling `WriteLine(int)` (because `byte` can be implicitly converted to `int`). An `int` can be represented as a `string`, so now it knows how to write the value to the console.

---

Just for fun, and to illustrate the concept, you could write a class like this:

```
public class MyBytes : List<byte>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "These are my bytes:" 
               + Environment.NewLine 
               + string.Join(Environment.NewLine, this);
    }
}
```

It inherits from `List<Byte>` and overrides `ToString()`. If you create an instance of `MyBytes`, populate it, and write it to the console:

```
var byteArray = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var myBytes = new MyBytes();
myBytes.AddRange(byteArray);
Console.WriteLine(myBytes);
```

You'll see that it calls your overridden `ToString()` method:

> These are my bytes:
>   1
>   2
>   3

That's just for illustration. Sometimes if we know that we're going to want to output a string representation of a class it makes sense to override `ToString()`, but I wouldn't create a whole class just for the purpose of overriding `ToString()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, is there any way to return the values in one line separated by a character? Again, thanks!

Comment: Sure, just replace `Environment.NewLine` with something else. You can build the string however you want. All that matters is that the function returns a string. I would just avoid any expensive, slow string concatenation.