# Reading raw data from Azure IoT hub trigger

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub, teltonika

I just want to start off by saying im new to programming in C# and Visual Studio.

I have a project where I am using a telematics unit to send sensor data into my Azure IoT hub.
I have the connection set up and I am trying to read the raw data coming from the telematics unit.
I have also set up the Azure IoT hub trigger in Visual Studio using the Azure function, IoT Hub Trigger v2.

See below for the code:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Teltonika_trigger_v3
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([IoTHubTrigger("messages/events", Connection = "EventHubConnection")]EventData message, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# IoT Hub trigger function processed a message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body.Array)}");
        }
    }
}
```

I am using a Teltonika telematics unit and I know that they use a special encoding called Codec8 (https://wiki.teltonika-gps.com/view/Codec)

Initially I am just interested in reading the raw bytes being sent to my IoT hub without any translation, how do I do this?

With the code above I get some
[very weird results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVpx4.png)

I have tried removing the `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` part but this just shows the data as "System.Byte[]".

How do I read the raw data coming into my IoT hub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body.Array)`, you're telling the Function to kindly take these bytes and treat them as Unicode, hence 'weird results'. If you just want to get the byte values as text, check out [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940883/c-converting-byte-array-to-string-and-printing-out-to-console/20011305#20011305).