# How to convert an array of signed bytes to float?

Tags: c#, arrays

I just got confused about how to convert an array of 4 signed bytes to a float number.

I just know for an array of unsigned bytes bts, probably I can use this function

```
BitConverter.ToSingle(bts, 0);
```

However, it looks like BitConverter.ToSingle only accepts byte array instead of sbyte array.

Could somebody give me some ideas please?

Thanks!

Comment: Because it convert object type, it doesn't convert values. Each 4 bytes will _become_ a single float value. Because bytes are just parts of float representation in memory then sign doesn't make any sense there. If you have to convert values then you have to create a new float array and to copy values there (one by one).

Comment: In what way does your signed bytes represent a float? Normally 4 unsigned bytes represent one float as said below.. If you give a concrete example we can give a solution

Comment: That is to say, if I got one signed array and another unsigned array but with the same bytes, theoretically they could become the same float number.....

Comment: But... How did you end up with the sbyte[]? I guess theoretically you can `BitConverter.ToSingle(bts.Select(b=>(byte)(b+128)).ToArray())`

Comment: If this is about a bit represenation of a float they should never have been `sbyte` in the first place. Check your dataflow for the problem upstream.

Comment: @user I cannot see how the answer you accepted relates to the question you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
float num = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < sbytesArr.Length; i++)
{
     num = (num | sbytesArr[i]) << i * 4;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I did't make my question clear, the result I want is the convert  4 sbytes in an array to a float number, instead of an array of float.. But thanks for your answer

Comment: Shouldnt you `or` that expression rather than `and`?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Float value = 5000.1234;
//
// Invoke BitConverter.GetBytes to convert double to bytes.
//
byte[] array = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
foreach (byte element in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
//
// You can convert the bytes back to a double.
//
Float result = BitConverter.Tofloat(array, 0);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: OP is asking for other way around

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your signed bytes are in an array named `sbts` you can first of all convert to an unsigned byte array, and then use `BitConverter.ToSingle()`.

```
byte[] bts = new byte[sbts.Length];
Buffer.BlockCopy(sbts, 0, bts, 0, sbts.Length);
float f = BitConverter.ToSingle(bts, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

[It is a little known fact that `byte` and `sbyte` are interchangeable at the CLR level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11977050/122718):

```
sbyte[] a = new sbyte[1];
byte[] b = (byte[])(object)a;
```

This code actually works at runtime. So can pass in the array that you have.

```
BitConverter.ToSingle((byte[])(object)bts, 0);
```

Comment: There is some more discussion of this technique here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829983/how-to-convert-a-sbyte-to-byte-in-c I think the key comment made there is: *What this does is change the compile-time type of the array. Useful technique, but it depends what ends up consuming the result. For instance, `System.Array.Copy(Array, int, Array, int, int)` looks at the runtime-type of the two arrays and will throw an exception if you try to copy a "real" byte[] to a `sbyte[]` masquerading as a `byte[]`.*

Answer (score 0):

Call `GetFloatValue` method passing una array of four sbyte as parameter

```
    public float GetFloatValue(sbyte[] data)
    {
        return bytesToFloat(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]);
    }

    private static float bytesToFloat(sbyte b0, sbyte b1, sbyte b2, sbyte b3)
    {
        int mantissa = (byte)b0 + ((byte)b1 << 8) + ((byte)b2 << 16);
        return (float)(mantissa * Math.Pow(10, b3));
    }
```