# C# sbyte array to BigInteger

Tags: c#, type-conversion, byte, biginteger

[image]I have to convert sbyte array to BigInteger. I am on universal windows platform. The BigInteger constructor only accepts byte[] and not sbyte[].
I cannot use byte[] since in C# byte is unsigned by default and I get higher values than 128.

The sbyte array is converted from byte array because when I compare the BigInteger value that C# is returning is different from the value in Java since java by default is using signed bytes and c# is using unsigned.

Any Solution ? 
BigInteger in java: 78214101938123633359912717791532276502
BigInteger in C#    30381787179362266836169791328776673082

Edit: I am trying to make a BigInteger from sbyte[] array. I am not trying to convert byte[] to sbyte[]

Comment: Why screenshot when you can copy/paste?

Comment: Flip your byte array. Java uses Big-Endian, C# (most likely) uses little-endian. More infos: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a sbyte\[\] to byte\[\] in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829983/how-to-convert-a-sbyte-to-byte-in-c)

Comment: I flipped my byte[] array to sbyte[] but now I need to create BigInteger from sbyte[] and the BigInteger constructor does not accept sbyte[]

Comment: I am not trying to convert byte[] to sbyte[] , its already done, I am trying to create BigInteger from sbyte[] instead of byte[] and I am not able to

Comment: Changing a `byte[]` to an `sbyte[]` is not flipping an array. e.g. normal: `[23, 14, 25, 64]` flipped: `[64, 25, 14, 23]`

Comment: The array order is fine. arrName[2] in java is -41 and in c# is 215

Comment: Why do you need to create a `BigInteger` from an `sbyte[]`? Just take the `byte[]`

Comment: Because after I get the BigInteger value, i need to encode it to base36 and substring to get some "id" that I need to send on a rest server. And since I am getting the BigInteger from unsigned bytes, I get different "id" than what I am supposed to

Comment: @DenkoMancheski I don't understand what you are trying to do. Changing a `sbyte[]` into an `byte[]` won't change the binary representation. Therefor it should work fine.

Comment: I added screenshot of what exactly the problem is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flip your byte array. Don't cast into an `sbyte[]`. Use a `byte[]`.

Here are your values as arrays (singed and unsigned):

Java values (signed): `58, -41, 124, -12, 24, 102, 14, 93, 79, -102, 72, 47, -62, 81, -37, 22`
Java values (unsigned): `58, 215, 124, 244, 24, 102, 14, 93, 79, 154, 72, 47, 194, 81, 219, 22`

C# values (signed): `22, -37, 81, -62, 47, 72, -102, 79, 93, 14, 102, 24, -12, 124, -41, 58`
C# values (unsigned): `22, 219, 81, 194, 47, 72, 154, 79, 93, 14, 102, 24, 244, 124, 215, 58`

Take a look at [Endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). As stated before Java uses `big-endian`, C# uses `little-endian`. Therefor flip your `byte[]` and stop casting it into an `sbyte[]`. It is not what you want.

Comment: How could I ... Thanks a lot, I thought this little-endian thing is connected with the conversion or something

Comment: Signed or unsigned have nothing to do with little or big endian. The sbyte[] conversion only re-interprets unsigned as signed. It does not reverse the entire array.